# Is it possible to replace specific piece of strings for a range of columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here's first [five rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy0f0.png) of a dataset:
`df.head()`

All numbers here are objects and I want to convert them to numeric. However, I want to change all columns at once with minimum lines of code. Here what I did:

```
df.loc[:,'median household income':'number of households'].str.replace(' ','')
df.loc[:,'median household income':'number of households'].str.replace(',','')
df.loc[:,'median household income':'number of households']=pd.to_numeric(df.loc[:,'median household income':'number of households'])
```

As a result, it shows following after running the cell:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: insteda of `df.loc`,  you can simply refer to the columns like `df['column_name']`. this will return a series, where str methods are applicable. you can put the logic in a for loop for each column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have the following data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'median household income': dict(a='1,000', b='2,000'),
    'number of households': dict(a='3,500', b='1,200')
})
```

You can write a function that will be applied to all elements of the dataframe using [DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method:

```
def replace_thousand_separators(item):
    return item.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '')
```

After that you can apply it together with the type transformation:

```
df.applymap(replace_thousand_separators).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because your slicing returns the dataframe not str object.

You can change the dtype of dataframe like this

```
df.astype('str').dtype
```

and then you can run str methods to it.